# Как отключать последний выбранный checkbox при условии, что можно выбрать не больше двух?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Есть 5 чекбоксов. Первый по умолчанию включен. Я выбираю второй, он включается, а как только включаю любой третий, то последний выбранный отключается.

То есть запоминать первый выбранный, второй выбранный, а при включении третьего чекбокса отключать второй.

UPD. Все должно быть чекбоксами. При отключении всех чекбоксов, все обнуляется и как только я выберу первый — он записывается как первый нажатый, включаю второй, запоминается второй нажатый. Выбираю третий — отключается второй. Простите за сумбур.

```js
function checkBoxLimit() {
 var checkBoxGroup = document.forms['form_name']['check[]'];   
 var limit = 2; //лимит
 
 for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxGroup.length; i++) {
  checkBoxGroup[i].onclick = function() {
   var checkedcount = 0;
   
   var first, second, third, fourth, fifth;
   var firstCheck, lastCheck;
   
   var clickNow = this.classList.value;
            console.log(this.classList.value);
            
            var arrClick = new Array();
            
   if (checkedcount == 1) {
       firstCheck = true;
       arrClick[arrClick.length].push(this.classList.value);
   } else {
       firstCheck = false;
   }
   
   if (checkedcount == 2) {
       lastCheck = true;
   } else {
       lastCheck = false;
   }
   
   if (checkedcount == 3) {
       firstCheck = false;
       lastCheck = false;
   }
  
            
   for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxGroup.length; i++) {
       
    checkedcount += (checkBoxGroup[i].checked) ? 1 : 0;
    
    first     = (checkBoxGroup[0].checked) ? true : false;
    second = (checkBoxGroup[1].checked) ? true : false;
    third        = (checkBoxGroup[2].checked) ? true : false;
    fourth          = (checkBoxGroup[3].checked) ? true : false;
    fifth    = (checkBoxGroup[4].checked) ? true : false;
    
   }

   
   
   if (checkedcount > limit) {
        this.checked = false;
   }
   
  }
 }
}
checkBoxLimit();
```

```html
    <form name="form_name" class="invisible_checkboxes">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="0" name="check[]">Первый</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="1" name="check[]">Второй</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="2" name="check[]">Третий</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="3" name="check[]">Четвертый</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="4" name="check[]">Пятый</label>
    </form>
```

Comment: Убери первый из группы. Преобразуй остальные в радио.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь то проблема отключение происходит по той причине что name один у тебя на всех. А вроде должен быть уникальный для всех.

Comment: Был неточен в описании, поправлю. Дело в том, что если чекбоксы не включены, то первым назначается тот, который я выберу. 

В общем нужно, чтобы все было чекбоксами и скрипт запоминал какой чекбокс стал первым, какой вторым. И отключать второй при выборе третьего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
let checked = [form.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]')];

form.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const el = e.target;
  
  if (el.tagName !== 'INPUT') {
    return;
  }
  
  if (el.checked) {
    if (checked.length === 2) {
    checked.pop().checked = false
  }
    checked.push(el);
  } else {
    if (checked[0] === el) {
      checked.shift()
    } else {
      checked.pop()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<form name="form_name" class="invisible_checkboxes" id=form>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="0" name="check[]" checked>Первый</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="1" name="check[]">Второй</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="2" name="check[]">Третий</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="3" name="check[]">Четвертый</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="4" name="check[]">Пятый</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. Я правильно понимаю, что данные записываются в массив и позже удаляются при проверке? 

У меня была такая мысль, в моем коде есть остатки использования массивов, но не хватает знаний для реализации. Пока сложно, буду пытаться вникнуть в код. Еще раз огромное спасибо!

Comment: Да массив, да удаляются или добавляются. В массиве всегда содержится не более двух элементов. `shift` удаляет первый, а `pop`  удаляет последний элемент

Comment: Немного костыльное решение. Почему вместо массива не хранить последний установленный чекбокс?

Comment: @234234  Попробуйте решить через последний чекбокс, я не против

Answer (score 0):

Для таких задач есть специальные [radiobutton](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/radio)

```html
     <form name="form_name" class="invisible_checkboxes">
            <label><input type="checkbox" class="0" name="check[]" checked>Первый</label>
            <label><input type="radio" class="1" name="check_radio" value="second">Второй</label>
            <label><input type="radio" class="2" name="check_radio" value="third">Третий</label>
            <label><input type="radio" class="3" name="check_radio" value="fourth">Четвертый</label>
            <label><input type="radio" class="4" name="check_radio" value="fifth">Пятый</label>
        </form>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но этот вариант не подходит. Я внес правки в вопрос. Дело в том, что первым включенным чекбоксом может быть любой. Все это для того, чтобы присвоить каждому включенному чекбоксу свою картинку. И картинки комбинируются в соответствии с выбранными чекбоксами, но не более двух.